# How can I put 2 block style controls at the same horizontal level in a webpage with css?

Tags: css

I have been using an html table to put 2 block style controls at the same horozontal level in a webpage. What is the best way to do this with css?

Comment: Does not work in ie6/ie7 on elements that are naturally *inline*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can floating the elements would do the trick?

html:

```
<div id="block1">Block 1</div>
<div id="block2">Block 2</div>
```

css:

```
#block1 {
  float: left;
}
```

...of course, this is just a demonstration example...you'd probably want to use a css class instead of hard coding id's...

Answer (score 2):

```
.blockStyleControl {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline;
```

That will have the elements render inline.

Comment: Yeah but he will lose height/width control.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

The most cross-browser compatible methods are to either float them, position them absolutely, or display inline or inline-block.

The less cross-browser compatible method is to use `display: table-cell`.